# Yii2 Paging with custom url rules

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to create paging in an application with the following custom rules

```
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [

            '/<id:\d+>' => 'news/view',
            '/<link>' => 'news/view',
             '/<technology>/<news>' => 'category/index',
            '/<technology>/<tags>/<title>' => 'category/tag',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' =>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',]
```

So how do I write the rule for paging which creates a url like this

`http://localhost/project/frontend/web/site/index?page=2&per-page=3`

I've tried this

`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<page>/<pg:\d+>/<per-page>/<pg2:\d+>' => 'site/index',`

but it's diverting to this rule instead

`'/<technology>/<news>' => 'category/index',`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else encounters a similar problem, I solved this by creating a route for the base url like so:

`'site/<title:\w+>'=>'site/index'`

then I created a route with the page parameter

`'site/<title:\w+>/<page:\d+>'=>'site/index'`

Everything worked like charm

Comment: Just a heads up, it seems like the rule with `<page:\d>` must come before your other rule