# Yii Paging with Pretty URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination, yii2, friendly-url

I have implemented pretty URLs that are working everywhere except paging. I have been searching for the solutions including [Paging with custom urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335785/yii2-paging-with-custom-url-rules)  
but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have this in my .htaccess

```
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Then I have these rules in my web.php file

```
      ''=>'site/index',
        'site/<title:\w+>'=>'site/index'
        'site/<title:\w+>/<page:\d+>'=>'site/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:\w+>' =>    
        '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        'site/find/<slug>' => 'site/find',
        '/<slug>'=>'site/find',
        'defaultRoute'=>'site/index'
```

The paging is supposed to work on site index. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are in incorrect order - you must put more specific one (with page in pattern) before more generic one (without page in pattern):

```
'' => 'site/index',
'site/<title:\w+>/<page:\d+>' => 'site/index',
'site/<title:\w+>' => 'site/index',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'site/find/<slug>' => 'site/find',
'<slug>' => 'site/find',
```